# Why am I not receiving any missions in GTA online PC?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I am level 7 on GTA Online and still haven't been contacted by any characters like Simeon or Lamar to get missions. Is this a glitch or is there something I'm not doing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to visit certain locations marked on the map in order to unlock interactions with NPCs (i.e. visit Lester's house to unlock heists at lvl 12). Also, check your settings menu to make sure you are not automatically refusing all job invites.

Answer (score 1):

In GTA Online, you have to get your missions yourself. There are just a handful of missions where you actually will be contacted. You can call all the NPCs via phone menu -> contacts. In the beginning, you only have simeon and this drug dealing guy in the appartment. When you reach higher levels, you'll unlock new NPCs which also have new missions for you.